# Tweets from Twitter Streaming API

Tags: python, twitter

Using Twitter Streaming API getting tweets from a specific query.

However some tweets came with different codification (there are boxes instead of words).

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: You might want to include some kind of example here; printing out the `repr()` of the text that doesn't display would help tremendously in diagnosing what codepoints are giving you problems.

Answer (score 2):

Use a different font, or a better method of displaying those.

All tweets in the streaming API are encoded with the same codec (JSON data is fully unicode aware), but not all characters can be displayed by all fonts.